# How to run the query that gets returned from Knex toNative?

Tags: javascript, knex.js

Knex toNative() might return something like this:

```
{
  sql: 'select "firstName", "lastName" from "table1" where (("age" >= $1 and "country" = $2) or ("age" < $3))',
  bindings: [ 25, 'NL', 25 ]
}
```

and naively, I thought I could run that like:

```
knex.raw(q.sql, q.bindings)
```

which doesn't work:

> Expected 3 bindings, saw 0

I use raw queries quite a lot, but always with ? and not $1 etc, so I figured this was the difference, and indeed, it works fine if I replace them. That is not so nice though.

What am I missing? How can I run the raw query as-is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with `.toNative()` when using Postgres. The reason appears to be because `knex.raw` only expects `?` and `??` to be used for positional arguments regardless of the underlying SQL dialect being used but `.toNative()` uses the postgres positional argument syntax of `$`.

If you remove the `.toNative()` call, so you only call `.toSQL()` on your query, that should give you the `sql` and `bindings` that you can pass directly to `knex.raw`.